# Spring form field dataType conversion, error

Tags: spring

This is Achinta, a new bee in the world of Spring. I need a small help to understand and resolve a problem which I am facing. I hope will find my answer here.

I am working on a sample Spring Web project. Here I have a Controller, Bean class and a Jsp page for UI and the other artifacts. Here is my Bean class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblLoadCriteria")
public class Load implements Serializable {
    private Integer loadID;
    private String loadCountry;
    private String loadState;
    private String loadCity;
    private Integer totalAirVolume;

    public Load() {//Constructor}

   //And Getter & Setter methods for loadID, loadCountry, loadState, loadCity & totalAirVolume
}
```

And the Spring form in my Jsp page.

```
<form:form id="systemForm" commandName="load" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/doSothing" method="POST" >
  <spring:message code="loadCountry" />: <form:input path="loadCountry" />
  <spring:message code="loadState" />: <form:input path="loadState" />
  <spring:message code="loadCity" />: <form:input path="loadCity" />
  <spring:message code="totalAirVolume" />: <form:input path="totalAirVolume" />

  <spring:message code="save" text="Save" scope="page" var="save" />
  <input id="next" type="button" onClick="submitSave();" />
</form:form>
```

And here goes the controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSothing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSothing(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("load") @Valid Load load ,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {

    loadService.saveLoad(load);

    return "forward:getApplicationRequirements";
}
```

Here the problem I am facing is, The "totalAirVolume" in the Load bean class is of type Integer and is bind to the UI page using spring form tags. But in the UI if I enter float value (F.Ex 12.12), instead of an integer and submit the page it gives me  status:400 error.

I am not so keen on javascript for validation for "totalAirVolume" field and looking for Spring way to handle it. Please help.

Your responses are highly appreciated.

Regards
Achinta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, before saving anything into DB, better to check each field if valid or not. I see you add @Valid before the model object 'Load', that means you want to use JSR-303 to validate the bean object. However, in your bean class, you don't add annotation to check anything, for example @size. 
Check this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validation-beanvalidation-overview, "7.8.1 Overview of the JSR-303 Bean Validation API".

Instead of using JSR-303 API, I suggest you create a validator that implements'org.springframework.validation.Validator', and make your rules.

And in your controller, before saving the object, call this validator to validate the object. If have  error, return error message to force input correct content.

@RequestMapping(value = "/doSothing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSothing(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,

```
LoadValidator lv=new LoadValidator ();
@ModelAttribute("load") @Valid Load load ,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {

    LoadValidator.validate(load);
    if(result.hasErrors()){
       //do something
        return something;
    }else {
        loadService.saveLoad(load);
        return "forward:getApplicationRequirements";
   }
}
```

For your reference, check "7.2 Validation using Spring's Validator interface" of the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your controller like this to return back to your form in case of validation/conversion errors:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSothing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSothing(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("load") @Valid Load load ,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
    // Return back to the form if the data is not valid
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "yourFormViewName"; // Name of the view for your form
    }
    loadService.saveLoad(load);
    return "forward:getApplicationRequirements";
}
```

And put this in your JSP form:

The `<form:errors>` element will display server side validation/conversion error messages.